# setOnClickListener in RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android

I have a structure in my android application

> LinearLayout > FrameLayout >ImageView(used as a FrameLayout
>   Background) & RelativeLayout > TextView & ImageView.

I need that when I click in the `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or FirstImageView ( because it is the Bigger Zone , the textView or 2nd Image view are small ) do an action.

I tried to add setOnClickListener to this item but didn't work.

This is my Code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

        RelativeLayout paleoFoodBackGround = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLytPaleoFoodHome);


        paleoFoodBackGround.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("1FOOD_LIST", "onClick: ");

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    public void clickFood(){
        Log.d("2FOOD_LIST", "onClick: ");
    }


}
```

This is my Layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="2.5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:weightSum="100">

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framePaleoFoodHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:paddingBottom="2.5dp">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewPaleoFoodBackGround"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recipes" />

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLytPaleoFoodHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"

        >

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgViewRecipesIconHome"
            style="@style/iconHome"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cooking"
            />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewRecipesTxtHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/textViewHomeSquare"
            android:text="@string/RecipesHome"

            android:layout_below="@id/imgViewRecipesIconHome"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
    <Framelayout> .... </Framelayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is `rootView` ?

Comment: may be you are getting id from wrong view, share all content of adapter.

Comment: Remove framelayout then try

Comment: Please add your return view in this question

Comment: remove clickable in textview and imageview

Comment: add return view and remove this `android:onClick="clickFood"` from relative layout.

Comment: just add android:focusable="true" property in the xml description of your relativeLytPaleoFoodHome layout. it will work.

Comment: @Mohit , I tried but don't work :S

Comment: @HemantParmar done, but it don't works :S

Comment: well you give match parent to your relative, may be its behind of your framework. try to wrap content and set height then check,

Comment: Well, same coding is working on my end. just tested.  are you sure you are launching the right fragment from activity. Also, put a toast in it as well, with Log.d() and try again.

Comment: @Mohit , yes sorry , it works I'm Launching the correct fragment. I restart the emulator and now it Works !! Ths !!!

Comment: Try this `android:clickable="true"` in your relative layout

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ImageButton instead of image. Also set your RelativeLayout to have android:clickable="true". Also set all children views that are not clickable with android:clickable="false"